# How to load amsdu_size=3 with the iwlwifi module

Tags: wireless, intel, iwlwifi, monitoring

I have a Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7265 WLAN and need to use it for monitoring.

To enable monitoring, [amsdu_size=3 needs to be loaded with the iwlwifi module](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_the_monitorsniffer_mode)

What command should I run to do this?

How do I know when the module has successfully loaded with this feature?

Answer (score 0):

The way to load the parameter is by first unloading the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

And then loading it with the required parameter:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi amsdu_size=3
```

As far as I know, the only way to confirm it is:

```
cat /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/amsdu_size
```

If the module loaded, the result should be *3*.