# Promiscuous/monitor mode

Tags: wireless, intel, iwlwifi

I have a Intel wireless N 7260. I want activate a promiscuous mode and i've see this post and:

[How to load amsdu_size=3 with the iwlwifi module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064976/how-to-load-amsdu-size-3-with-the-iwlwifi-module)

However, for me, the first command (sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi) return Fatal the module is in use and i can't add amsdu size. How can proceede? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have likely erased the original contents of /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
To restore do `gedit admin:///etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Paste in the following

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Save and exit

Comment: Ok i use that and now working the command but the promiscuous mode in wireshark and tcpdump doesn't work. Any suggestions?